# .pdf to .docx in RStudio

Tags: r, pdf, rstudio

I want to convert a .pdf file to a .docx file in RStudio. I tried reading the .pdf and writing to the .docx but it doesn't differentiate the title, spaces, tables, or graphics (the original document has a title, text, several graphics, several tables). I need that the .docx file looks exactly like the .pdf file.

Comment: RStudio is just an editor. You need to find a package that can convert PDF to DOCX, although that won't be easy. A PDF is essentially print instructions, not text. It doesn't even have tables, those are emulated.

Answer (score 0):

The following approach can be considered :

```
library(RDCOMClient)

wordApp <- COMCreate("Word.Application")
wordApp[["Visible"]] <- TRUE
wordApp[["DisplayAlerts"]] <- FALSE
path_To_PDF_File <- "yyy.pdf"
path_To_Word_File <- "yyy.docx"

doc <- wordApp[["Documents"]]$Open(normalizePath(path_To_PDF_File),
                                   ConfirmConversions = FALSE)
doc$SaveAs2(path_To_Word_File)
```